# How to upload a large file than 100MB via Data Management API on the Autodesk Forge?

Tags: curl, postman, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

Final result:

My apologies for the mistake.
I set wrong value to `Content-Range` in my http requests.

Example is here:

1. Original file size: 5242880
2. Chunk size: 2097152
3. Required HTTP Request count: 3

Thus, the correct `Content-Range` is following these:

1. bytes 0-2097151/5242880
2. bytes 2097152-4194303/5242880
3. bytes 4194304-5242879/5242880

Thanks to your advice, i got to test with:

- cURL
- Postman
- Charles
- Node.js
- C#
- Swift

---

Second try with Postman:

I tried again a following API with [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).

- [PUT buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName/resumable](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-resumable-PUT/)

I use [rst_basic_sample_project.rvt](https://developer.static.autodesk.com/forgeunified/releases/samples/rst_basic_sample_project.rvt) that provide by Autdesk.
The file is 5693440 bytes.

```sh
$ du -b rst_basic_sample_project.rvt
5693440 rst_basic_sample_project.rvt
```

I divided with the following command.

```sh
# Chunk size is 5 MB.
split -b 5242880 rst_basic_sample_project.rvt "temp/data-"
```

So, i got `data-aa` and `data-ab`.
Next, try to use [PUT buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName/resumable](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-resumable-PUT/).

Send `data-aa` to API. HTTP Request is here:

```
PUT /oss/v2/buckets/${MY-BUCKET-KEY}/objects/${MY-OBJECT-NAME}/resumable HTTP/1.1
Host: developer.api.autodesk.com
Authorization: Bearer ${MY-TOKEN}
Content-Range: bytes 1-5242880/5693440
session-id: j45e05
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

"<data-aa binary>"
```

I got HTTP 202. It's expected result.
And, send `data-ab` to API. HTTP Request is here:

```
PUT /oss/v2/buckets/${MY-BUCKET-KEY}/objects/${MY-OBJECT-NAME}/resumable HTTP/1.1
Host: developer.api.autodesk.com
Authorization: Bearer ${MY-TOKEN}
Content-Range: bytes 5242880-5693440/5693440
Content-Type: application/stream
session-id: j45e05
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

"<data-ab binary>"
```

I got `HTTP 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable`.
It's unexpected result.

---

First try with cURL:

Please show me how to upload a large file.
I'm trying to upload a file larger than 100MB using the API below.

- PUT buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName/resumable
  https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-resumable-PUT/

First of all, i simply want to know the API response and verify.
Therefore, I sent HTTP PUT Request with cURL.

- The large file is 157286400 bytes (Using command `dd if=/dev/random of=bigfile bs=1M count=150` )
- Data chunk size is 5242880 bytes (Using command `split -b 5242880 bigfile "temp/data-"` )

cURL command is here:

```
curl \
    -v \
    -X PUT "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/${MY-BUCKET-KEY}/objects/${MY-OBJECT-NAME}/resumable" \
    -H "Authorization:Bearer ${MY-TOKEN}" \
    -H "Content-Length: 5242880" \
    -H "Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8" \
    -H "Content-Range:bytes 1-5242880‬/157286400 " \
    -H "Session-Id:111111111" \
    --data @temp/data-aa # One of the files created by splitting a large file with the split command.

# PUT /oss/v2/buckets/${MY-BUCKET-KEY}/objects/${MY-OBJECT-NAME}/resumable HTTP/1.1
# Host: developer.api.autodesk.com
# User-Agent: curl/7.69.0
# Accept: */*
# Authorization:Bearer ${MY-TOKEN}
# Content-Length: 5242880
# Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8
# Content-Range:bytes 1-5242880‬/157286400 
# Session-Id:111111111
```

API response return `HTTP/1.1 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT`.
How to upload a large file than 100MB via Data Management API on the Autodesk Forge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a tool, and don't need to implement the resumable upload yourself (and you can use VSCode), you should check out VS-Code Forge Tools.

https://github.com/petrbroz/vscode-forge-tools

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-visual-studio-code

Our team has used it to upload GB sized models during testing.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about `vscode-forge-tools`. It's very cool!

Answer (score 0):

Try [buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName/resumable](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-resumable-PUT/)

You may then split larger files into chunks and specify a range in the header for each request to upload the chunks to avoid timeouts and other networking issues, e.g.:

```
curl -v "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/bucketexamplekey/objects/objectKeyFoo/resumable"
  -X PUT
  -H "Authorization:Bearer p0vNqwggSc4EOJdhR4KkTVyJFIzQ"
  -H "Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
  -H "Content-Range:bytes 1-15/100"
  -H "Session-Id:-811577637"
  --data ...
```

You might also want to use this tool [here](https://forge-tools-hub.now.sh/uploader) (guide [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/meet-forge-tools-hub-jamstackserverless-tools-download-derivatives-svf-and-view-models-offline)) for this purpose.

Comment: I tried to upload on https://forge-tools-hub.now.sh/uploader. I set chunk size 2 MB.
Upload failed with the following pattern:

- Test data 1: dd if=/dev/random of=bigfile bs=1M count=150
- Test data 2: [rst_basic_sample_project.rvt](https://developer.static.autodesk.com/forgeunified/releases/samples/rst_basic_sample_project.rvt)

Can you upload in your environment?

Comment: [The uploader](https://forge-tools-hub.now.sh/uploader) doesn't clearly working. Talking on [GitHub - Failed to upload file](https://github.com/dukedhx/forge-tools-hub/issues/3)

Comment: Update my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61097888/13257344).